# How to get the value of a Select value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get the option value of a dynamically populated Select button so that I could use to get the value I needed in my database. I dont know how to get the  `$giftName` value. I tried using jquery and javascript but I don't know how to integrate it to my code because I'm still new to this languages. Here's a part of my code that might help you:

```
<div class="row ml ">
    <div class="col-lg-6 ">
        <select id="giftList" name=''gifts" class="pull-left mb">
            <option value=""></option>
                <?php 
                    $sendGiftSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE isDelete = 'false' ORDER BY price ");
                    while($sendGift = mysql_fetch_assoc($sendGiftSql)){
                        $giftName = $sendGift['name'];
                       echo("
                            <option value =". $giftName.">"  . $giftName. "</option>;
                       ");
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <b style="float: right;">Cost://This is where the value of the select button will be used...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: All of the options have the value of gifts1 so you will not know which one was selected. Remove the value attribute and just show the $giftName i.e. echo "<option>".$giftName."</option>";

Comment: Get the value when? Is there a form being submitted wrapping what is shown? Not clear what you are needing and when

Comment: @charlietfl I dont have a form yet sir but I just wanted to get the value of the option tag every time I choose one of the options in the select tag so I could use it to retrieve some data in my database. I hope it's a bit clear now.

Comment: You should set an `id` on the parent `div` where you want to display the selected value and need some javascript to update the text from the input on change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

`<option>" . $giftName. "</option>;`

to

`echo("<option value =". $giftName.">" . $giftName. "</option>");`

later you can fetch the selected value using `$('#giftList')`.

Comment: still you are not able to fetch the selected dropdown value ? btw can you post your jquery code ,which you used to fetch the dropdown value.

Comment: I still cant sir. This one sir. $('#giftList option:selected').val(). To be honest, I don't know where to put that and what to do next.

Comment: @KaelJasper: I have created a jsfiddle with possible markup that would be generated from your mysql script here https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/1gkbm13p/, you  can play with jsfiddle to know how jquery works